# WPF: programmatically opening context menu loses data context

Tags: wpf, xaml, datacontext

I would like to reuse the context menu of a `ListViewItem` by adding a toggle button within the item itself which opens it.
The context menu itself works correctly,
however when I open it through the toggle button (simply setting its property `IsOpen` to `True`) the commands inside don't work anymore.
It seems the context menu does not have the `DataContext` anymore.

```
<ListView>
 <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
     <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
         <Setter Property="ContextMenu">
             <Setter.Value>
                 <ContextMenu>
                     <MenuItem
                         Header="Restore"
                         Command="{Binding RestoreCommand}" />
                     <MenuItem
                         Header="Delete"
                         Command="{Binding DeleteCommand}"/>
                 </ContextMenu>
             </Setter.Value>
         </Setter>
     </Style>
 </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>

 <ListView.View>
     <GridView>
         <!-- My columns here -->
         <GridViewColumn>
             <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                 <DataTemplate>
                     <ToggleButton IsChecked="{Binding Path=ContextMenu.IsOpen, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListViewItem}}}"/>
                 </DataTemplate>
             </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
         </GridViewColumn>
     </GridView>
 </ListView.View>
```

Any suggestions?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the context menu opened indirectly in this way does not have a `DataContext`.
In order to "assign" it one, you should use the property `PlacementTarget` to indicate on which control it is bound to.

To achieve this task you can either create a custom behavior, or, if you prefer a purely xaml solution:

```
<!-- xmlns:b="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xaml/behaviors" -->
 
<GridViewColumn>
<GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <ToggleButton
            x:Name="MoreActionsButton"
            IsChecked="{Binding ContextMenu.IsOpen, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListViewItem}}, Mode=OneWayToSource}">
            <b:Interaction.Triggers>
                <b:EventTrigger EventName="Checked">
                    <b:ChangePropertyAction
                        TargetObject="{Binding ContextMenu, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListViewItem}}}"
                        PropertyName="PlacementTarget"
                        Value="{Binding ElementName=MoreActionsButton}" />
                </b:EventTrigger>
            </b:Interaction.Triggers>
        </ToggleButton>
    </DataTemplate>
</GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
</GridViewColumn>
```